# Bounded & Norm space

Tags: normed-spaces, bounded-variation

Can someone help me on this exercise ? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$||Tf||_\infty=\sup_{s\in[0,2]}|Tf(s)|\le\sqrt{2}||f||_\infty$$

Take $f$ the function constant equal to $1$ and prove that $||T||=\sqrt 2$.